# Fatal error: Call to undefined function (works within the same PHP but not when seperate)

Tags: php

I tested the code from within the same *.php file and it works but when I try to put my `mail` function into a separate file, I get an error.

File 1

```
<?php
include_once("settings.php");
include_once("include/frontend_functions.php");
include_once("include/login_functions.php");
include_once("include/email_functions.php");
include("include/session.php");

$poArgs = array(
          'user_id' => $_SESSION['js_user_id'],
          'order_id' => $_SESSION['order']['id'],
          'subtotal' => $_SESSION['order']['quote']['subtotal'],
          'tax' => $_SESSION['order']['quote']['tax'],
          'secondary_tax' => $_SESSION['order']['quote']['secondary_tax'],
          'soda_tax' => $_SESSION['order']['quote']['soda_tax'],
          'tip' => $_SESSION['order']['quote']['tip'],
          'discount' => $_SESSION['order']['quote']['coupon_amt'],
          'total' => $_SESSION['order']['quote']['total'],
          'payment_method' => $_POST['check_pay_method'],
          'payment_collected' => 0,
        );
$order_id = $_SESSION['js_user_id'];

if (function_exists('send_order_confirmation_email')){
          send_order_confirmation_email($order_id);
        }
        else {
          echo "$send_order_confirmation_email not defined";
        }
?>
```

File 2 (include/email_functions.php)

```
<?php
include_once("../settings.php");
include_once("frontend_functions.php");
include_once("login_functions.php");
include_once("order_functions.php");
include_once("jsmail.php");

function send_order_confirmation_email($order_id)
{
//send - only called if $placed!=0
  global $db;
  $order = $db->get_full_order_info_by_id($order_id);

  $user = $db->get_user_info_by_id($order['user_id']);
  $to_email = $user['email'];
  $to_name = $user['fname'] . ' ' . $user['lname'];


  $store = $db->get_store_location_by_id($order['store_id']);
  $wait_time = $store['wait_time'];
  //$wait_time = $db->get_store_waitime($order['store']['id']);
  $from = $db->get_admin_content_by_code('notifications_email');
  $fromname = '';
  $subject = 'Thank You For Your Order!';



  $html = "Your meal is being freshly prepared at our store <b><u>" . $store['name']  . "</u></b>.<br /><br />";
  if ($order['delivery_type'] == 'D') {

    $html .=  "<span style='font-weight: bold; font-size:12px!important;'>Estimated delivery time is ". $wait_time . ".</span><br />";
    $html .= "<br />
                        As soon as your order is on it's way, we will notify you via email. Stay tuned!";
  } else {
    $html .= "<span style='font-weight: bold; font-size:12px!important;'>Your order will be ready for pickup in " . $wait_time . ".</span><br />";
  }



  $html2 = "<table>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <table width='100%'>
                        <tr style='font-size: 12px !important;'>
                            <th colspan='2' style='background: rgb(245,250,240);'>RECEIPT - ORDER #" . $order['oxid'] . " Order placed on " . date('m/d/y', strtotime($order['orderplaced_ts'])) . ', at ' . date('h:ia', strtotime($order['orderplaced_ts'])) . "</th>
                        </tr>
                        <tr style='font-size: 10px !important;'>
                            <td>";
  if ($order['delivery_type'] == 'D') {
    $html2 .= "<h3 style='font-size:12px!important; margin: 0;'>Deliver To:</h3>";
  } else {
    $html2 .= "<h3 style='font-size:12px!important; margin: 0;'>Pickup At:</h3>";
  }
  $html2 .= get_row($order['company'], '', '<br />') . "
                                    " . get_row($order['address_1']) . "
                                    " . get_row($order['address_2'], '', '', true) . "
                                    " . get_row($order['address_3'], '', '', true) . "
                                    " . get_row($order['city'], '', ',', true) . "
                                    " . get_row($order['abbreviation'], ' ') . "
                                    " . get_row($order['zip'], ' ') . "
                                    " . get_row($order['phone'], '', '', true) . "
                                    " . get_row($order['ext'], ' ext. ', '') . "
                            </td>
                            <td>" . get_row($order['comments'], "<h3 style='font-size:12px!important; margin: 0;'>Delivery Instructions:</h3>") . "</td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <table cellspacing='0'>
                        <tr style='font-size: 12px !important;'>
                            <th align='left' style='background: rgb(245,250,240);'>ITEM</th>
                            <th align='center' style='background: rgb(245,250,240);'>QTY</th>
                            <th align='center' style='background: rgb(245,250,240);'>PRICE</th>
                        </tr>";

  if ($order) {
    $item_ids = array();
    foreach ($order['items'] as $item) {
      if ($item['menuitem_id'] > 0) $item_ids[] = $item['menuitem_id'];
    }
    $db_items = $db->get_menuitem_list($item_ids);
    $db_items = $db->get_id_keyed_array($db_items);
    foreach ($order['items'] as $item) {
      if ($item['quantity'] > 0) {
        $html2 .= "<tr style='font-size: 10px !important;'>
                                        <td align='left' style='border-bottom: 1px solid rgb(160,206,103); padding-top: 10px;'>";
        if ($item['fav_id'] > 0) {
          $fav = $db->get_favorite_by_id($item['fav_id']);
          $html2 .= "<span style='font-weight: bold; font-size:12px!important;'>" . $fav['favorite_nickname'] . " (" . $db_items[$item['menuitem_id']]['name'] . ")</span><br />";
        } else if ($item['menuitem_id']) {
          $html2 .= "<span style='font-weight: bold; font-size:12px!important;'>" . $db_items[$item['menuitem_id']]['name'] . "</span><br />";
        } else {
          $html2 .= "<span style='font-weight: bold; font-size:12px!important;'>Custom Item</span><br />";
        }

        if ($item['customizations']) {
          $html2 .= get_row(get_customization_list($item['customizations']));
        }

        $html2 .= get_row($item['whofor'], 'For: ');

        if ($item['choppingpreference'] || $item['dressingpreference'] || $item['includebread'] || $item['specialrequest']) {
          $html2 .= "<h4>Preferences</h4>
                                                    <ul>
                                                        " . get_row($item['choppingpreference'], '<li>Chopping Preference: ', '</li>') . "
                                                        " . get_row($item['dressingpreference'], '<li>Dressing Preference: ', '</li>') . "
                                                        " . get_row($item['includebread'], '<li>Include Bread: ', '</li>') . "
                                                        " . get_row($item['specialrequest'], '<li>Special Instructions: ', '</li>') . "
                                                    </ul>";
        }
        $html2 .= "</td>
                                        <td align='center' valign='top' style='font-weight: bold; font-size:12px!important; border-bottom: 1px solid rgb(160,206,103); padding-top: 10px;'>" . $item['quantity'] . "</td>
                                        <td align='center' valign='top' style='font-weight: bold; font-size:12px!important; border-bottom: 1px solid rgb(160,206,103); padding-top: 10px;'>" . CURRENCY . $item['quantity'] * $item['price'] . "</td>
                                    </tr>";
      }
    }
  }

  $html2 .= "<tr style='font-size: 12px !important;'>
                            <td valign='top' style='padding-top: 10px;'>";
  if ($order['payment_method']) {
    $html2 .= "<h3 style='font-size:12px!important; margin: 0;'>Payment Info:</h3>";
    if ($order['payment_method'] == 'Credit Card') {
      if ($order['payment_details']) {
        $html2 .= $order['payment_details'] . "<br />";
      } else {
        $html2 .= $order['payment_method'] . "<br />";
      }
    } else {
      $html2 .= $order['payment_method'] . "<br />";
    }
  }

  $html2 .= "<br />
                                <span style='color: rgb(255,139,60); font-weight: bold; font-style: italic; font-size:10px!important;'>For food delivery/pickup related issues, please call " . $db->get_store_phone($order['store_id']) . ". For billing questions, please contact " . $db->get_admin_content_by_code('billing_email') . "</span></td>
                            <td valign='top' style='font-weight: bold; padding-top: 10px;'>";
  if ($order['subtotal']) {
    $html2 .= "Subtotal:<br />";
  }
  // removed >0 if statement, screwed up placement of totals
  if ($order['tip']) {
    $html2 .= "Tip:<br />";
  }
  // added extra line break to match total currency
  if ($order['tax'] > 0) {
    $html2 .= "Tax:<br /><br />";
  }
  if ($order['shipping'] > 0) {
    $html2 .= "Delivery Fee:<br />";
  }
  if ($order['total']) {
    $html2 .= "Total:<br />";
  }
  $html2 .= "</td>
                            <td align='right' valign='top' style='font-weight: bold; padding-top: 10px;'>
                                " . get_row($order['subtotal'], CURRENCY) . "<br />
                                " . get_row($order['tip'], CURRENCY) . "<br />
                                " . (TAX == "YES" ? get_row($order['tax'], CURRENCY) : "") . "<br />
                                " . (SHIPPING == "YES" ? get_row($order['shipping'], CURRENCY) : "") . "<br />
                                " . get_row($order['total'], CURRENCY) . "<br />
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>";

  $plain = str_replace(array('<br />', '<strong>', '</strong>', '<ul>', '</ul>', '<li>', '</li>', '<table>', '</table>', '<tr>', '</tr>', '<td>', '</td>', '<th>', '</th>', '<h3>', '</h3>', '<h4>', '</h4>', '<span>', '</span>'), '', $html . $html2);
  $plain = preg_replace(array('/<table.*?>/', '/<tr.*?>/', '/<th.*?>/', '/<td.*?>/', '/<h3.*?>/', '/<span.*?>/'), '', $plain);
  //add in html2 + 1
  $html_template = make_html_template('order_confirm', $html, $html2);
  //only send this email IF the order has been fully processed, i.e. NOT while waiting for Level Up

  multiMail(array('email' => $to_email, 'name' => $to_name), $subject, $plain, $html_template, array('email' => $from, 'name' => $fromname), array('email' => $from, 'name' => $fromname), array(array('email' => ORDER_BCC_EMAIL, 'name' => ORDER_BCC_EMAIL_NAME)));
}
?>
```

If I place the function from File 2 into File 1 and replace the function call, the email gets sent. When I separate the function into a new file, it stops.

This function is being called from within an IF statement, but from my understanding this is perfectly legal. I've tried outside the IF statement and still got an error.

What am I missing here?

EDIT:

> error code: PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function send_order_confirmation_email() in /app/checkout-payment.php on line 21

Also, I deleted everything inside the function to replace with:

```
function send_order_confirmation_email($order_id){
//send - only called if $placed!=0
  echo $order_id;
  return true;
}
```

And the call failed....Is my call wrong?

Comment: Which is the error row number?

Comment: @lingo it fails on the function call itself from File 1, line 22

Comment: What does fail? what is the error? Please be a little more specific, paste the error in your question, the error seems to be something inside that function but not the function call itself.

Comment: @taxicala The function works if its inside the same PHP file, so I doubt its the function - unless you have something in mind for me to investigate?

Comment: paste the error codes

Comment: @zairwolf added error code and more troubleshooting steps.

Comment: Try using require_once instead of include_once

Comment: have no idea. plz simplify your codes to debug

Comment: As Jessica suggested, try using require_once. Include will not fail if something went wrong except dispaying E_WARNING, which you can have disabled. If something fails while using require it will give you the proper message and stop executing the script.

Comment: @Jessica - that worked....damn Heroku... = (